# ¿Como imprimir en un cheque independiente de la impresora?

Tags: php

Debo con información almacenada enviar a imprimir un cheque, actualmente genero el cheque en un PDF con DomPdf el tamaño de papel lo configuro con esta librería y las posiciones del texto lo hago con CSS/HTML, pero debo configurar cada impresora con un tamaño de papel personalizado, como hacer que sea independiente de la impresora, que simplemente den clic en imprimir y la impresora que escojan me reconozca el tamaño del papel y las posiciones del texto.

Como lo realizo actualmente:

```
/**
** Funcion Imprimir Cheque
** @param id_cheque Identificador del cheque
** @return Void - Genera Pdf
**/
public function imprimirCheque($id){

$Cheque = Cheque::find($id_cheque);

       // Traigo los datos de configuración del papel        

        $ConfigIC = ConfigImpresionCheque::find(1);
        $p1 = $ConfigIC->paper_p1;
        $p2 = $ConfigIC->paper_p2;
        $p3 = $ConfigIC->paper_p3;
        $p4 = $ConfigIC->paper_p4;

        $orientation = $ConfigIC->orientation;
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();

        // Funcion Crear_banco_a Genera un HTML 
        // con la información del Cheque y
        // posiciona los datos con CSS.          

        $html = $this->crear_banco_A(
            $Cheque->numero_cheque,
            $Cheque->fecha_giro, 
            $Cheque->valor_cheque, 
            $Cheque->beneficiario,
            $Cheque->nit_beneficiario
          );

        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

        // Configuro DomPdf con los datos de configuración del papel

        $chequePaper = array($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4);
        $dompdf->setPaper($chequePaper, $orientation);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres que se imprima el ticket directamente o vía navegador?

Comment: Hola @Muriano como esta actualmente uso la opciones que aparecen cuando abre el Pdf, entiendo que eso seria según la pregunta desde el navegador. agrego pantalla en la descripción del problema.